# Robot Framework Run Process with stdout to a file having leftover process

Tags: python, robotframework

I am running a process and storing the output in a file as this:

```
Run Process   ${command}   stdout=file.txt   shell=true   alias=myprocess
```

It works fine, the output are stored in the file.txt. The issue is after I terminate the process, I can not remove the file.txt.

```
Terminate Process   myprocess
Remove File   file.txt              <- this will throw error below

# WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: u'c:\\temp\\RF_wqysnx\\file.txt
```

I have this very brittle solution which is sleeping for 15 secs between Terminate Process and Remove File. This is the current solution:

```
Terminate Process   myprocess 
Process Should Be Stopped   myprocess 
Sleep   15s 
Remove File   file.txt
```

This works fine, but why there is a leftover process. My assumption is Robotframework has some leftover process on this "stdout" file. I have been looking for a better soltuion for this, does anyone know? Any kinda of help is appreciate, thanks :).

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is without knowing what process you are running, but `Terminate Process`keyword documentation has a hint: `Stops the process gracefully or forcefully.` Your process may take some time to exit. Check if `Wait For Process` could help you in this variable delay.

Comment: I have had "plenty" of issues with terminating processes in Windows when the started process has child processes..  At the time, i didnt end up debugging of RF could still handle those and wrote this; https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-seleniumtestability/blob/master/src/Helpers/__init__.py